# What does 'a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope' mean?

Tags: typescript

I read this content from TS docs:

> ```
> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module.
>
> Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).
> ```

I am confused: What does 'global scope' mean here?

For example:
If I have 2 files in the same dir: module.ts and global.ts. And function `add` is defined in global.ts. Can I call function `add` directly in moudle.ts (without import add from global.ts)? I tried this but got error:

```
src/index.ts:2:11 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'add'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Modules have their own scope. Top-level declarations in modules are not global declarations, as they would be in non-module scripts.

```html
<script>
let a = 1; // A global variable
</script>
<script type="module">
let b = 2; // A module-scope variable (not a global)
</script>
<script>
console.log(typeof a); // "number"
console.log(typeof b); // "undefined"
</script>
```

The message is telling you that since you have a file with no `import` or `export` in it, TypeScript treats it as a non-module script and evaluates it at global scope.

> For example: If I have 2 files in the same dir: module.ts and global.ts. And function `add` is defined in global.ts. Can I call function `add` directly in moudle.ts (without import add from global.ts)? I tried this but got error:

Yes, **if**:

1. `global.ts` has already been executed, so the function exists; and
2. TypeScript knows that `add` is available at global scope

To achieve #2 above, you have to [declare `add` in the global namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) in a declaration file or similar.

But I don't recommend it. Instead, make `global.ts` a module by having it export `add` or anything else it provides (and probably changing its name), and import what you need from it in `module.ts`.